# Form tag being removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, x-editable

i am currently writing a piece of code using AngularJS with X-editable and ui-bootstrap, my problem is in this part of the code:

```
<div ng-repeat='task in CurrentOIDs | filter:criteria | orderBy:OrderField:ReverseSort'> 
    <div class='row {{!areCollapsed[task.OIDid] | selected}}' 
         style='background-color: {{ task.Status | color }};' 
         ng-click="checkCollapse(task.OIDid, !rowform.$visible);">
        <div style='width: 5%;' class='cell OIDid'>
            {{ task.OIDid }}
        </div>
        <div style='width: 5%;' class='cell'>
            <span buttons='no' onbeforesave='checkPriority($data)' 
                  editable-select="task.Priority" 
                  e-id='priorityInput' e-name="priority" 
                  e-form='rowform' 
                  e-ng-options="p.value as p.text for p in priorities">
                {{task.Priority}}
            </span>
        </div>
        <div style='width: 13%;' class='cell'>
            <span buttons='no' onbeforesave='checkTopic($data)' 
                  editable-text='task.Topic' e-name='topic' 
                  e-form='rowform' e-required e-list="Topics">
                {{ task.Topic }}
            </span>
        </div>
        <div style='width: 20%;' class='cell'>
            <span buttons='no' onbeforesave='checkCategory($data)' 
                  editable-text='task.Category' e-id='categoryInput' 
                  e-name='category' e-form='rowform' 
                  e-required e-list="Categories">
                {{ task.Category }}
            </span>
        </div>
        <div style='width: 35%;' class='cell'>
            <span buttons='no' onbeforesave='checkTask($data)' 
                  editable-text='task.Task' e-id='taskInput' 
                  e-name='task' e-form='rowform' 
                  e-required>
                {{task.Task}}
            </span>
        </div>     
        <div style='width: 6%;' class='cell'>
            {{ task.Added }}
        </div>
        <div style='width: 6%;' class='cell'>
            {{ task.Target }}
        </div>
        <div style='width: 5%;' class='cell'>
            <span buttons='no' onbeforesave='checkOwner($data)' 
                  editable-text='task.Owner' e-name='owner' 
                  e-form='rowform' e-required 
                  e-list="Owners">
                {{ task.Owner }}
            </span>
        </div>
        <div style='width: 5%;' class='cell Status'>
            <span buttons='no' onbeforesave='checkStatus($data)' 
                  editable-number='task.Status' e-min='0' 
                  e-max='100' e-name='status' e-form='rowform' 
                  e-required>
                {{ task.Status }}%
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div collapse='areCollapsed[task.OIDid]'>
        <div style='height: 30px;' ng-show='rowform.$visible'>
            <form onbeforesave='saveTask($data, task.OIDid)' 
                  editable-form name='rowform' 
                  shown="inserted == task">
                <button type='submit' ng-disabled="rowform.$waiting" 
                        id="saverowedit">
                    OK
                </button>
                <button type="button" ng-disabled="rowform.$waiting" 
                        ng-click="rowform.$cancel()" 
                        id="cancelrowedit">
                    CANCEL
                </button>
            </form>    
        </div>
        <div style='height: 30px;' ng-show='!rowform.$visible'>
            <button id='editButton' style='width: 25%;' title="Edit" 
                    ng-click="rowform.$show()">
                <?php include("svg/edit.svg")?>
            </button> 
            <button id='archiveButton' style='width: 25%;' title="Archive">
                <?php include("svg/archive.svg")?>
            </button>
            <button id='mailingButton' style='width: 25%;' title="MailingList">
                <?php include("svg/mail.svg")?>
            </button>
            <button id='historyButton' style='width: 25%;' title="History">
                <?php include("svg/history.svg") ?>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For some reason, when i inspect the resultant code the FORM tags are being removed completely, which leaves only the buttons, but obviously they will serve no purpose if they are not in a form tag.

my question is what could cause this to happen? and how can i fix it?

thanks

Comment: Do you have a form in a form?

Comment: I have formatted your question code to be "readable" one and you can't imagine how painful it was so please give some "care" to your code.

Comment: fair enough, apologies. as far as i can tell no i do not have nested forms. Could it be because all of the forms generated have the same name?

Answer (score 1):

HTML only allows one `<form>` tag, and thus you'll see that

If you use `<ng-form>` instead of `<form>` it'll allow you to overcome this obstacle.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm

Comment: Cheers for the answer, but if i recall correctly (been a while) i had a missing closing form tag in my code which was screwing everything up.. still thank you for answering :)

Comment: Well, it was posted 2 years ago, so I'm glad you figured it out :) My problem took forever to figure out and I was very frustrated so I figured I'd post my answer, at the very least so I see the answer next time I encounter it :)